# Prevent SelectedIndexChanged when removing an entry in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listbox

So when I click the delete button and have someone selected in the listbox this code runs

```
'check if a member is selected
    If LBmembers.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have not selected a member to delete.")
    ElseIf LBmembers.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim i As String = LBmembers.SelectedItem
        Dim dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\Gotrek65\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ice Mining Calculator\Ice Mining Calculator\members.mdb "
        Dim SqlQuery As String =
            "DELETE FROM tblMembers WHERE Member = @ID;"
        'remove member(i) from database
        Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
            Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.Variant).Value = i
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        TBtimestart.Text = ""
        TBtimeend.Text = ""
        TBtimecycle.Text = ""
        RBpro.Checked = False
        RBret.Checked = False
        RBcov.Checked = False
        RBskiff.Checked = False
        RBmack.Checked = False
        RBhulk.Checked = False
        LBmembers.Items.Remove(LBmembers.SelectedItem)
    End If



Private Sub LBmembers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LBmembers.SelectedIndexChanged
        'unfinished
        'if the selected idex changes then the individual stats should be retrieved from database and updated
        Dim i As String = LBmembers.SelectedItem
        Dim dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\Gotrek65\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ice Mining Calculator\Ice Mining Calculator\members.mdb "
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ShipCode, CycleTime FROM tblMembers WHERE Member = @ID;"
        Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
            Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("'@ID'", OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = i
                'EXCEPTION when deleting data from tblMembers function "Parameter @ID has no default value." 
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If reader.Read() Then
                        'reader is  outputing "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader"
                        'but running the same query in access just yields 4 blank values...
                        TBtimestart.Text = reader.ToString(0)
                        TBtimeend.Text = reader.ToString(1)
                        Dim j = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ToString(2))
                        TBtimecycle.Text = reader.ToString(3)
                        If j = 1 Then
                            RBpro.Checked = True
                        ElseIf j = 2 Then
                            RBret.Checked = True
                        ElseIf j = 3 Then
                            RBcov.Checked = True
                        ElseIf j = 4 Then
                            RBskiff.Checked = True
                        ElseIf j = 5 Then
                            RBmack.Checked = True
                        ElseIf j = 6 Then
                            RBhulk.Checked = True
                        Else
                            RBpro.Checked = False
                            RBret.Checked = False
                            RBcov.Checked = False
                            RBskiff.Checked = False
                            RBmack.Checked = False
                            RBhulk.Checked = False
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

trying to prevent the SelectedIndexChanged from running when deleting a entry/member from the listbox. Curious if there is a possible way to do this because this is just started to get silly.

**Additional information about the program.**

The LBmembers(listbox) is used to update a database from said list. Also when you select an entry in the listbox(LBmembers) it should go to the database(access DB tblMembers(columns: Member(text), StartTime(text), EndTime(text), ShipCode(number), CycleTime(number), WorkPercent(number), Share(number)) should be pulled from said database and populated into their specific boxes.

Let me know if you need more code information.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because there is nothing in your homework which says to be sure to disable that event.  So show the code illustrating the real issue.  If you just dont like the event, dont put any code in the handler.

Comment: Temporarily letting an event have no effect is pretty normal, most easily accomplished with a simple bool flag.  But this sounds like a bug.  Yes, the selected index properly changed because you removed an entry from the listbox.  But the selected item didn't change.

Comment: post updated with far more code. I see what your point out Plutonix and lets try not to use the homework word here as this is not a program for work on school. I am just trying to learn .net by programming something useful for a community.

Comment: just use a flag to ignore the event when you click the Delete button.  be sure to clear it afterwards

Comment: I am not sure why you want to disable this event at all. If the  purpose of the event handler is to display the current selected item and another one becomes selected because you deleted the previous one, then let the event do its job!

Comment: the way it is coded, it depends on SelectedItem which was just deleted, so it likely crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple flag to ignore the change when desired:

```
Private ignoreChange As Boolean
Private Sub DeleteBtn_Click(...
    ignoreChange = True
    '... lots of code
    LBmembers.Items.Remove(LBmembers.SelectedItem)

    ignoreChange = False
End Sub

Private Sub LBmembers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender ...
   If ignoreChange Then Exit Sub
   ' lots more code

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I was trying to research before actually asking how.